# Processing real-time stream using Netcat

Tags: netcat

I'm trying to process a real-time email stream and I'm familiar with BASH.

I'm using netcat to listen to the stream. Emails are returned in JSON and new emails are delineated with a carriage-return.

I'm trying to figure out how to write each email to it's own unique file.  From there, I can process the JSON according to my needs.

Several people I've talked to say that I 'shouldn't use BASH for this purpose, but that I can probably get it to work'.  I'm looking for feedback from others.

But also, I'm hopeful that someone can assist me with using nc to output to a file on each carriage return.

Thanks

**** Example ****

```
nc localhost 123
```

will open the stream and start listening

The returned info looks like:

```
"to\":\"guy@mail.com\",\"x-connecting-ip\":\"12.12.12.12\",\"subject\":\"[Test Email] Email to fax=ABCDE_1234B1234\"
```

New emails are separated by a carriage return.  I want to write each of those emails to a unique file and keep listening to the stream.

Comment: So, it's not actually JSON? At least from your example, it doesn't appear to be. Can you post a pastebin with a slightly bigger example of the input data (at least 3 or 4 emails)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use the "split" command

```
nc localhost 123 | split -l 1
```

This will create 1 file per line named "xaa","xab","xac",etc. Check the split man page for more options.

Comment: YES!  Can you help me understand this though?  Why are the files being written as xab, xaa, and so forth?  I'd rather set them as variable:  `date +%b%d%y%H%M%S`   I don't see anything about this on the man page.

Comment: They're written as xaa,xab... because you're reading stdin and there isn't a filename, so it just uses X. There's no option to change the suffix, although you can add an additional suffix with "--additional-suffix=$(date +%b%d%y%H%M%S)", but the file would still be named "x" with a two letter suffix in addition to yours. You could then use another shell script to rename it the way you want, it it's absolutely necessary.